# TinyMCE Editor not showing inside JQuery UI Dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tinymce, jquery-ui-dialog, tinymce-5

The editor textarea is not showing inside the jQuery UI dialog modal. Instead, the status bar is showing right below the toolbar.

I am using :

- jquery-3.5.1.min.js
- tinymce v5.7.1
- bootstrap v4.5.3

[image: tinymce body not showing]

Perhaps is it a conflict? Below is my code.

```
<div id="testdialog">
    <p>TEST</p> 
    <div>
        <textarea cols="35" rows="5" id="testTinyMCE" name="testTinyMCE" style="padding-left: 10px"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<button type="button" onclick='testtiny()'>Try</button>
```

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#testdialog').dialog({
        'title':'Add Form Field',
        'resizable': false,
        'dialogClass':'form-content', 
        'modal': true,
        'autoOpen': false,
        'open':function(){
            initTiny();
        },
        'width':650
    }); 
});

function initTiny(){
    tinymce.init({
        selector: '#testTinyMCE'
      });
}

function testtiny(){
    console.log('opening the dialog');
    $('#testdialog').dialog('open');
}
</script>
```

Comment: Suspect it's sort of an order or operation. I would suggest initializing TinyMCE first and then Dialog, before opening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi all thank you for answering my question. It is indeed due to css conflict, so my fix is to modify the position in **tox-edit-area** and **tox-statusbar** class.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/bjhmL61a/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  function initTiny(selector) {
    tinymce.init({
      selector: selector
    });
  }

  initTiny("#testTinyMCE");

  $('#testdialog').dialog({
    title: 'Try TinyMCE',
    resizable: false,
    classes: {
      "ui-dialog-content": "form-content"
    },
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 650
  });

  $("#tryButton").click(function() {
    $('#testdialog').dialog('open');
  });
});
```

With just a few adjustments, it seems to be working as expected.